# Increase number of visible tabs in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have total of 5 fragments inside a Viewpager and I want to display 2 tabs on either side of the current visible tab.

Example : My current tab is 2 . And I want tab 0, tab 1 to left and tab 3,tab 4 to the right to be displayed at once.

I tried setting **viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)** but it didnt' work. I still see only 1 tab displayed on either sides. What am I missing?

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    titleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.titlestrip);
    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
 }

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private Context context;

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
    super(fm);
    context = c;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {

        case 0:
            return new FirstFrag();
        case 1:
            return new SecondFrag();
        case 2:
            return new ThirdFrag();
        case 3:
            return new FourthFrag();
        case 4:
            return new FifthFrag();
        default:
            return new SecondFrag();
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 5;
}
}
```

Comment: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` only saves the number of fragments that are loaded before they are shown. For ex. if you have fragment 2 shown, the adapter will load fragment 1 and 3 so they are ready to be shown when you scroll on your viewpager. You may have to implement custom views if you want to show those pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this issue by using TabLayout. Posting the code for future readers.

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
>
>    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>         android:id="@+id/awesome_toolbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="74dp"
>         android:background="#ff31353f"
>         android:paddingTop="20dp"
>         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
>         app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>         android:id="@+id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>     android:id="@+id/pager"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment {
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity());
    adapter.addFragment(new FirstFrag(), getResources().getString(R.string.frag1));
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondFrag(), getResources().getString(R.string.frag2));
    adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFrag(), getResources().getString(R.string.frag3));
    adapter.addFragment(new FourthFrag(), getResources().getString(R.string.frag4));
    adapter.addFragment(new FifthFrag(), getResources().getString(R.string.frag5));
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `ViewPager` adapter. Override the `public Fragment getItem(int position)` method, and create a custom `Fragment` that will contain the current fragment and the fragment in position-1 in the left, position+1 in the right. You may have to override the `public int getCount()` method too. I didn't try an implementation like this before but I think this is the way to approach this.

Comment: I have already overriden getItem and getCount methods to return 5 fragments.

Comment: no i mean you have to create a custom fragment which takes for example 3 fragments and put them side by side (like the view you want to achieve). And then return that custom fragment.

Comment: Well, there could be a better way.

Comment: You may find a library, but i dont think that `ViewPager` supports that by itself